# Stored Proc slower from application than Management Studio

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, apache-commons-dbcp, jtds

We have a stored proc which runs pathetically when called from application (Spring - DBCP - jtds) infact timesout after 10 minutes, but runs in 30 seconds when executed from SQL Server Managament Stuido. Can someone provide leads into this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This normally indicates a parameter sniffing issue.

See [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) for details.