# Stored proc timeout in VB.net but runs quickly in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have an issue I hope you can help with.

Developing an vb.net web app, using VS 2013 and SSMS. I have a stored proc which runs very quickly when tested in SSMS. But, when I run an executenonquery in Visual Studio it takes forever, then times out.

What I've tried: To make sure it wasn't a connection related issue, etc... I created a super simple test stored proc with the same input params. The only code change I made was change from "StoredProcSlow" to "StoredProcTest". That's it. This code ran perfectly fine in both SSMS and in Visual Studio. So, I know the vb.net code is fine.

Please note: The Input params of both stored procs (the original and my test) were exactly the same.

I can't try profiler because I'm using an Azure SQL Server database.

Any ideas what could be the problem or how I can troubleshoot further?

UPDATE: I narrowed it down the the UPDATE of a specific table within the stored proc. Even when I do a dummy update, such as "UPDATE dbo.Table1 SET DisplayName = 'XXXXX' WHERE (DisplayName = 'XXXXX')" it still hangs. Disabled all triggers. Still hangs. Any ideas appreciated.

UPDATE 2: I CLONED the offending Table1 into a test table (structure and data). Then I used this new test table in the stored proc. It ran very good. This gets more confusing by the minute!

Comment: This happens a lot to me.  There's got to be an answer somewhere on the site . . . something about parameter sniffing perhaps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stored Proc slower from application than Management Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504273/stored-proc-slower-from-application-than-management-studio)

Comment: That answer actually needs to be improved, it's link only.  Alas.

Comment: I narrowed it down the the UPDATE of a specific table within the stored proc. Even when I do a dummy update, such as "UPDATE dbo.Table1 SET DisplayName = 'XXXXX' WHERE (DisplayName = 'XXXXX')" it still hangs. Disabled all triggers. Still hangs. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for significantly different performance is likely different execution plans.  Run the query below to see if you have multiple cached plans for the same proc:

```
SELECT  qs.plan_handle
      , qp.query_plan
FROM    sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
        CROSS  APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) est
        OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) AS qp
WHERE   est.objectid = OBJECT_ID('dbo.your_proc');
```

Multiple plans may exist due to different session settings.  The attributes that compose the key are described in the SQL Server Books Online (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189472.aspx).

For a thorough discussion on this topic, see Erland Sommarskog article: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html.  Note that not all the DMVs referenced in the article are available in Azure SQL Database but the basic concepts apply.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I ran it but the result set had no records. I double checked to make sure the sp name was correct.

Comment: @WebDevGuy2, have you recently executed the proc?

Comment: Yes I have, when I was testing it to make sure it was working quickly.

Comment: I tried it again this morning after running it a few times. I have about 7 records now from your query.